# R simex with nls + power mean method

Tags: r, nls

I am attempting to analyze a dataset using nonlinear least squares that has both measurement error and heteroscedasticity. I was able to fit the model using `nls()` in R and adjust for heteroscedasticity by weighting the observations by a power function of the fitted values (a technique known as the power mean method). However, when I additionally try to correct for measurement error using the `simex` package in R, I get the following error:

```
Error: measurement.error is constant 0 in column(s) 1
```

Which is strange because I have specified a nonzero measurement error. I have pasted example code below which reproduces this error.

```
library(simex)
set.seed(123456789)
x = runif(n = 1000, min = 1, max = 3.6)
x_err = x + rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 0, sd = 0.1)
y_mean = 100/(1+10^(log10(100)-x)*0.75)
y_het = y_mean + rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 0, sd = 10*x^-2)
y_het = ifelse(y_het > 0, y_het, 0)
w = (100/(1+10^(log10(100)-x_err)*0.75))^-2

nls_fit = nls(y_het ~ 100/(1+10^((log10(k)-x_err)*h)), start = list("k" = 100, "h" = 0.75), weights = 1/w)

simex(nls_fit, SIMEXvariable = "x_err", measurement.error = 0.1, asymptotic = F)
```

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen would migrating to stackoverflow be a better option?

Comment: If you want so we can migrate it for you, since it has a reproducible code example it should be on-topic there

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Yes I think I would like to have this migrated.